# Cannot access the database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have a small VB.Net 2005 application and MS SQL 2005 database.

It's a small ADO.Net application the thing is surprising me is that I did this project 100%
and it's working fine with me but after I send the project with the database to a friend. It did not work. I send the database as `[DB_name].bak`, my friend tried to restore it, it gave an error. he tried to create the database in his local machine, when he tried to connect it to the database it gave him a strange error:

> `(login failed for user 'win7-PC\Win7'), maybe this error occurred'
>   because there is no (win7-PC\Win7) user in SQL Security`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because your app is using windows authentication to connect to the database. Simply add the user (win7-PC\win7) to SQL as a database owner for that database.